# Can't find .net framework 4.5 advanced services in windows features

Tags: iis-7, windows-7-x64, .net-framework-version

I'm running IIS7 on windows 7 with .net framework 4.5 installed but can't find the .net framework 4.5 advanced services in the windows features screen.
I need to turn on WCF and it is supposed to be inside the advanced services features.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any .NET 4 things need to be configured via command line on Windows 7. Run https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732012(v=vs.110).aspx